# TYPO3 onepager + normal pages structure

Tags: typo3

I am very new to TYPO3 and I am having problems achieving the following:

A website structure looking like so

-home

— Sub content 1

— Sub content 2

— Sub content 3

— etc..

-page 1

-page 2

-etc…

The home page should be collecting the “sub content 1” “sub content 2” & "sub content3", so it should behave like a one pager. 
And the other pages should be behaving as ‘normal’ pages.

I downloaded the FluidTypo3 kickstarter package. And followed then this tutorial: https://worksonmymachine.org/blog/onepage-design-with-fluidtypo3 where it is described how to achieve a onepager with FluidTypo3.
I managed so far to get this result:

-root

—Sub content 1

—Sub content 2

—Sub content 3

As soon as I add a new level:

-root

—home

—— sub content 1

—— sub content 2

The Onepager effect stops functioning, and the sub pages are not being collected anymore. I did configure under “Edit page” which template should be used, yet no success.

I am stuck to this step and can’t figure out why this is not functioning? Ideas?

I have Typo3 6.2 installed.

Comment: Please read `TypoScript in 45 minutes tutorial` first. Most likely you failed to configure the right `Page ID` to start collection subpages and their content.

Comment: entryLevel should be the keyword your looking for in https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/MenuViewHelper.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  TRUE: Entry-level was THE keyword. My problem is fixed :-) Thanks for the link! I definitely need to look into the manual.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: 
You have added one level to your menu so your old page structure not correct anymore. You use a

> v:page.menu

And it should have the correct access point to you page structure.

If you check the [specification of this ViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/MenuViewHelper.html), you find the

> entryLevel

However the specification says only:

> Optional entryLevel TS equivalent of the menu (integer)

You need to search a bit more to understand its working, and if you see the [TypoScript documentation for HMENU](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html) then you see how it works:

> Defines at which level in the rootLine the menu should start.
>
> Default is "0" which gives us a menu of the very first pages on the
>   site.
>
> If the value is < 0, entryLevel is chosen from "behind" in the
>   rootLine. Thus "-1" is a menu with items from the outermost level,
>   "-2" is the level before the outermost...

*(You got already the help in the comments, but I wanted to write here an answer based on the feedbacks)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. this makes things even clearer!!